# Validating dates within the current month

Tags: javascript, vb.net, validation

I'm working on a date field for an invoice. The date selected for the invoice date cannot be any day outside the current month.

Here is my code:

```
at Page_Load:
 Dim firstOfTheMonthDate As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime.Now)
                Me.compareValidatorDate.ValueToCompare = firstOfTheMonthDate.ToString("d")
```

my Private Function

```
Private Function FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(dateTime As DateTime) As DateTime
        Return New DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1)
    End Function
```

client side:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvDate" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtInvDate">Invoice Date:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInvDate" MaxLength="20" CssClass="L5 DateCal" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtInvDate" 
                    Text="The date field is required!" runat="server" />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="compareValidatorDate" ControlToValidate="txtInvDate" 
                    Type="Date" Operator="LessThan" ErrorMessage="Date must be from this month!"
                    Display="Dynamic" runat="server" />
```

The problem I'm having is that validation does not occur, or at least, if any date is entered other than blank or null, the invoice date is saved. How can I improve my code?

CREDIT to Karl Anderson for help with the code.

Comment: Your validation says that the value entered in txtInvDate must be less than the first day of an arbitrary month.  That doesn't seem to be the validation behaviour you say you're after, where you want it to be greater than or equal to the first of the current month, and less than or equal to the last day of the current month.  Is my understanding of your requirements correct?

Comment: @Adrian - thanks for noticing that, I had it straight in my head, but wrote the exact opposite logic like you said.

Comment: Yes Adrian, absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for not noticing this earlier, but I gave you the incorrect logic earlier.

The better solution would be to use a `RangeValidator`, like this:

Code-behind (`Page_Load`):

```
Dim firstOfTheMonthDate As DateTime = FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime.Now)
Dim endOfTheMonthDate As DateTime = LastDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime.Now)
Me.rangeValidatorDate.MinimumValue = firstOfTheMonthDate.ToString("d")
Me.rangeValidatorDate.MaximumValue = endOfTheMonthDate.ToString("d")
```

Code-behind (utility functions):

```
Private Function FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(dateTime As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return New DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1)
End Function

Public Function LastDayOfMonthFromDateTime(dateTime As DateTime) As DateTime
    Dim firstDayOfTheMonth As New DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1)
    Return firstDayOfTheMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
End Function
```

Client side:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvDate" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtInvDate">Invoice Date:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtInvDate" MaxLength="20" CssClass="L5 DateCal" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtInvDate" 
    Text="The date field is required!" runat="server" />
<asp:RangeValidator id="rangeValidatorDate" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtInvDate" Type="Date" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: Since the original requirement is to have the date be "within the current month" maybe the `rangeValidatorDate.MaximumValue` should be `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month));`.  It's a mouthful, but it should give the last day of the current month.

Comment: @Adrian - Wow, I am out of it today. Good looking out. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Adrian and Karl. I just got enough rep to actual give props so I will. I really appreciate the assistance, and I'm able to interpret what the code is actually doing at each step between my desired breakpoints. Debugging is going well.